# How to nest these Serializes without facing AttributeError: 'BlogPost' object has no attribute 'review_set'

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I followed Dennis Ivy proshop Tutorial He used the same approach as the code is

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_reviews(self, obj):
        reviews = obj.review_set.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Now I need a Blog for the eCommerce Project and I created another app named blog and Created the models as

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Like How To Treat Hypertension etc")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              default='/placeholder.png')
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    youtubeVideoLink = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True , blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)

class BlogPostReview(models.Model):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating)
```

But when I serialize them via same approach as mentioned above....

```
class BlogPostReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPostReview
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blog_post_reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)  

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_blog_post_reviews(self, obj):
        blog_post_reviews = obj.review_set.all()
        serializer = BlogPostReviewSerializer(blog_post_reviews, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

This error comes

```
in get_blog_post_reviews
    blog_post_reviews = obj.review_set.all()
AttributeError: 'BlogPost' object has no attribute 'review_set'
```

How to solve this problem or what I'm doing wrong and what need to be fixed. What would be another apporach obv there would be.... And I don't know why Dennis Ivy used `review_set` in his code. If someone know why we use `_set` and what are the circumstances please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to update your `get_blog_post_reviews` method:

```py
def get_blog_post_reviews(self, obj):
    blog_post_reviews = obj.blogpostreview_set.all()  # <- this line has changed
    serializer = BlogPostReviewSerializer(blog_post_reviews, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

The original worked because there was a model named `Review`, so the automatically created reverse name was `review_set`. Your model is named `BlogPostReview`, so the reverse is `blogpostreview_set`.

More information about [reverse relationships in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: Those underscores won't be there, it would be `blogpostreview_set`

Comment: Thank You ! Both AbdulAzizBarkat &@MattRowbum.  It's working now.